# DropDown binding in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, dropdown

I have this code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gestisci IP" SortExpression="GestisciIp">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGestisciIP" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="GestisciIP" 
            DataValueField="GestisciIP" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("GestisciIP") %>'>
             <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="True" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="False"  />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GestisciIp") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The datasource contain the value of a field selected on the current user (user id) and it can be True or False.
My problem is that **I want the dropdown to always shows the 2 options True and False, but it should also have the selected  value got from the datasource**.

If I remove the 2 lines

```
<asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="True" />
<asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="False"  />
```

it only shows the value got from the db, if I leave these lines it shows 3 values: the one got from the db and True, False added by this code.
So, how can I do this? I hope I was clear enough, thanks

---

**IT'S DONE!**
Thank you again

**ASPX**

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gestisci IP" SortExpression="GestisciIp">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGestisciIP" runat="server">

                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="True" />
                             <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="False"  />
                        </asp:DropDownList>--%>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GestisciIp") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
 Private Sub GridView2_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowCommand
  If e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
        Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

        Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("Label2"), Label)

        ViewState("LabelValue") = lbl.Text
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso GridView2.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex Then
        Dim ddlGestisciIP As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlGestisciIP"), DropDownList)
        Dim LblddlGestisciIP As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("LblddlGestisciIP"), Label)
        ddlGestisciIP.Items.Add(New ListItem("True", "1"))
        ddlGestisciIP.Items.Add(New ListItem("False", "0"))
        If Convert.ToString(ViewState("LabelValue")) <> "" Then

            ddlGestisciIP.SelectedValue = ddlGestisciIP.Items.FindByText(Convert.ToString(ViewState("LabelValue"))).Value
        End If
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub GridView2_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowUpdating
    Dim ddlGestisciIP As DropDownList = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(GridView2.EditIndex).FindControl("ddlGestisciIP"), DropDownList)

    SqlDataSourceUtenti.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [Utenti] SET [RfProfilo] = @RfProfilo, [Nome] = @Nome, [Cognome] = @Cognome, [Username] = @Username, [Password] = @Password, [Badge] = @Badge, [IpCorretto] = @IpCorretto, [GestisciIp] = " & ddlGestisciIP.SelectedValue & " WHERE [IdUtente] = @Original_IdUtente"

End Sub
```

Comment: What's this look like? `SqlDataSource3`

Comment: SELECT [GestisciIP] FROM [Utenti] WHERE ([IdUtente] = @IdUtente)
basically it get a boolean value from the db

Comment: did you got the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,add Onrowdatabound event to your gridview and bind your dropdownlist in that event.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceUtenti" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="IdUtente" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                BorderWidth="3px" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating"  >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RfProfilo" HeaderText="RfProfilo" 
                        SortExpression="RfProfilo" Visible="False" />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" SortExpression="Nome" />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cognome" HeaderText="Cognome" 
                        SortExpression="Cognome" />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                        SortExpression="Username" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Profilo" SortExpression="Profilo">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Nome" DataValueField="idProfilo" 
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RfProfilo") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NomeProfilo") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# mascheraPassword(Eval("Password").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Badge" HeaderText="Badge" SortExpression="Badge" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IP di origine" SortExpression="IpCorretto">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IpCorretto") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblIpCorretto" maxlength="16" runat="server" Text='<%# limitaCaratteri(Eval("IpCorretto").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>




                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gestisci IP" SortExpression="GestisciIp">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGestisciIP" runat="server">

                        </asp:DropDownList>

                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GestisciIp") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>




                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                CommandName="Update" Text="Aggiorna" ForeColor="White"></asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Cancel" Text="Annulla" ForeColor="White"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Edit" Text="Modifica"></asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Delete" Text="Elimina"></asp:LinkButton>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>



                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

in code behind

```
 Protected Sub GridView2_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
      If e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
            Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

            Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("Label2"), Label)

            ViewState("LabelValue") = lbl.Text
        End If

    End Sub



    Private Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso GridView2.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex Then
            Dim ddlGestisciIP As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlGestisciIP"), DropDownList)

            ddlGestisciIP.Items.Add(New ListItem("True", "1"))
            ddlGestisciIP.Items.Add(New ListItem("False", "0"))
            If Convert.ToString(ViewState("LabelValue")) <> "" Then

                ddlGestisciIP.SelectedValue = ddlGestisciIP.Items.FindByText(Convert.ToString(ViewState("LabelValue"))).Value
            End If
        End If



    End Sub
```

First ,With the use of RowCommand Event of the Grid View , Get the value of the Edited Label into the ViewState,then Use viewstate and Handle your RowDataBound

and to upadate your data you can use roeupdate event,like follows

```
 protected void Gridview2_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
//add code for updating values in database
}
```

Comment: I converted it in VB and get a Null reference Exception error on ddlGestisciIP.Items.Insert(1, li2) saying to use New to create an object instance.

Comment: Ok, problem is that rows on datagrid are editable, so when page load it shows a label with the value got from the db (label2), when press Edit the label turns into a dropdownlist (ddlGestisciIP). So I added an IF to check if control is not nothing. Now I have another problem: how to mantain the label2 value when going to edit mode? I should do: Read label value and store it, then, if going to edit mode, use it to fill the dropdown. But label2 doesn't exists anymore on the page when enter edit mode...

Comment: I edited the question to include the progress, can you help me to the final step? :-D

Comment: is there any progress ?you got the solution?

Comment: Hi, no, do you have some other advice? Feel free to answer in C#, I can understand it.

Comment: Hi Gabriele Cozzolino,I have edited my answer,Try it,I hope it works,Good luck:),Please let me know if it is done or not.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand one thing:  Label LblddlGestisciIP = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LblddlGestisciIP") what's LblddlGestisciIP? It isn't an object in the aspx page...

Comment: Same error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'GestisciIP', table 'dbVirtualTimb.dbo.Utenti'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Sorry, maybe a bit of information is missing: after pressing Edit button on the row, it turns in "Update" button, so I change the value of ddlGestisciIP dropdown and then press Update to save new value to db. Is here that I get the error.

Comment: I realize today that I missed the "OnRowDatabound" and "OnDataBound" strings in gridview, but if I add those I get the error "BC30456: 'Gridview2_RowDataBound' it's not a member of 'ASP.adminpanel_aspx'" Without those I get to the point where I can Edit the datagrid row, but after changing the dropdown value and pressing Update I get the error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'GestisciIP', table 'dbVirtualTimb.dbo.Utenti'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated."

Comment: you are getting that error because in code behind it is "Gridview1_RowDataBound" and you have to change it to  "Gridview2_RowDataBound" according to your code..please copy and paste your complete code..

Comment: Of course I have changed it to Griedview2 when added to my code :-) I updated my question with full code, please notice that in that code "OnRowDatabound" and "OnDataBound" on gridview aspx are missing because led to a compilation error "BC30456: 'Gridview2_RowDataBound' it's not a member of 'ASP.adminpanel_aspx'" Thank you for your time!

Comment: you didn't entered the code you used  for updation,

Comment: I have edited my answer,have a look at it..u can check where the error occurs by putting break points on your code,all the best

Comment: Hi, thank you! In RowUpdating I added SqlDataSourceUtenti.UpdateCommand = "update query from ASPX" + [GestisciIp] = " & ddlGestisciIP.SelectedValue & " WHERE [IdUtente] = @Original_IdUtente" but the value of ddlGestisciIP.SelectedValue is always the initial value of the component and do not count the user selection.

Comment: I should probably use FindControl to get the correct dropdown used by the user, but the RowUpdating event do not have  "e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs" as RowDataBound. Anyway, I edited my question with the query I use to update the db. It is in aspx page, created by VS after I configured gridview and datasource, originally I didn't used the RowUpdating event at all at worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I get an error "BC30456: 'Gridview2_RowDataBound' it's not a member of 'ASP.adminpanel_aspx'" if I add  OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating"

Comment: It's DONE! I added this in RowUpdating:  
Dim ddlGestisciIP As DropDownList = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(GridView2.EditIndex).FindControl("ddlGestisciIP"), DropDownList)

SqlDataSourceUtenti.UpdateCommand = update query & ddlGestisciIP.SelectedValue & " WHERE [IdUtente] = @Original_IdUtente"

Thank you again!

Comment: really!!!wow...atlast after 13 days its done...feeling too good...Congrats and thank you so much for being so patient and trying all the solutions...

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correct, you only want the values TRUE and FALSE, so, you don't need a datasource to do this...

Remove this properties DataSourceID, DataTextField, DataValueField and SelectedValue...

Try it please.

Comment: No, I want it to display True and False but it has to show the selected value got from the database.